# electron js how to call a function rendered in index

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm going crazy to be able to call a function that I have rendered in an index and then execute that function with globalShortcut, I was researching and found that IPC could perform, but all the examples are to use functions from the main and not from the index. any idea that can guide me

Comment: Please may you share a text-based [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to trigger a function defined in your renderer from your main thread?

Comment: exactly, I want to activate from main a function that I have in the index

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `nodeIntegration` set to true and `contextIsolation` set to false, [as advised by the Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content). To trigger a function in your renderer process from the main thread you can use [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main/) and [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer/) (these modules are part of Electron).

First, you need to expose an API for the renderer using [`contextBridge`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge/). This can be done with a [`preload.js`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model/#preload-scripts) file that has access to all modules like the main thread.

Example:

**main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

function createMainWindow(){
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            enableRemoteModule: false,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    });
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    createMainWindow();
});
```

**preload.js**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    send: (channel, data) => {
        // Whitelist channels
        let validChannels = ['toMain'];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
        }
    },
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        let validChannels = ['fromMain'];
        if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
            // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
        }
    },
});
```

Then, in your renderer process you can use `window.api.send(channel, parameters);` to send messages to the main thread and `window.api.receive(channel, parameters);` to listen for incoming ones. Similarly, you would use `ipcMain.on(channel, (event, parameters) => { });` in the main process to handle messages from the renderer. However, to directly send messages to it, you have to use `webContents`, like so: `mainWindow.webContents.send(channel, parameters);`.

In your case, to execute a function in the renderer, you would call `mainWindow.webContents.send('fromMain', 'trigger-function');` in the main process; and listen for this event in your renderer like so:

```
window.api.receive('fromMain', (parameters) => {
    if (parameters === 'trigger-function'){
        // Call your renderer function here
    }
});
```